# Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap DLL

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I'm a beginner programmer in C++. Recently, I started working on image processing using C++. I am trying to define and use the simple functions like :

```
Matrix MVE(Matrix R)
{
    Matrix *X = P.T();
    invX = *X->Inverse();
    delete X;  
    return invX;
}
```

or

```
Matrix MVE(Matrix R, double tolerance)
{
    int n = R.Y();
    int m = R.X();
    Matrix X(n,m);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        M[i][m] = tolerance * R[i][m-1];

    return M;
}
```

There are no problems in release mode, but when I run in debbug mode , I get the following error:

Windows has triggered a breakpoint in plappd.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in plappd.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while plappd.exe has focus.

I am calling the constructors and operations for Matrix class from other DLL file.

I tried changing from Debug Multithreaded (/MTd) to Debug Multithreaded DLL (/MDd), as suggested in many forums, but it did not help to solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use some tools (like Walker Dependency) to check that the exe and the dll are using the same run time? (typically you check for MSVCR**.DLL)
The exe and the dll have to use the same run time in your case.

**Edit:**
Also, you said you changed "from Debug Multithreaded (/MTd) to Debug Multithreaded DLL (/MDd)"
Both are debug mode. Since it seems that your Run Time was working fine in your Release configuration, i guess you should use the same: 
It should be Multi-threaded (/MT) or Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

Comment: I tried Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) in release mode, and it worked. On the other hand, both Multi-threaded (/MT) and Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) give me the same error in debug mode.